# Is "Vale actualmente" proper when comparing currencies?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, finanzas

Is it proper to use

> Vale actualmente...

when comparing two exchange rates? For instance,

> 1 USD Vale actualmente 0.89 EUR

with a meaning roughly equal to "Is worth"? Or is there a better translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the same words in Spanish, and I'm sure it is widely used in many Spanish speaking regions.

Other options are *equivale actualmente a*, or *corresponde actualmente a*:

For example:

> 1 USD equivale actualmente a 0.89 EUR
>
> 1 USD corresponde actualmente a 0.89 EUR

Notice that with these two options, the preposition **a** must be used before the second value. This doesn't happen if you use **vale...**.